# How to calculate deviation equation using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a math equation in which I have to use the first column of a file to calculate a mean absolute deviation and I am stuck trying to use awk to calculate it

[image: this is the equation:]

In which `α` corresponds to the values of the first column of the `test.2` file(shown below), and `n` is the number of lines the file has (excluding the first one).

the file would look something like this

```
 79
  1    4.4278   2.2139   2.1869   3.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
  2    6.9588   3.4794   2.9968   5.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
  3    6.5200   3.7258   2.8564   2.0000   1.0000   0.0000   0.0000
  4    6.4927   3.7101   2.8477   2.5000   1.0000   0.0000   0.0000
  5    6.2338   3.5621   2.7648   2.5000   1.0000   0.0000   0.0000
  6    6.1514   3.5150   2.7384   2.5000   1.0000   0.0000   0.0000
  7    6.5048   3.7171   2.8515   2.5000   1.0000   0.0000   0.0000
  8    6.6012   3.7722   2.8824   2.5000   1.0000   0.0000   0.0000
```

With values going until it reaches 79 lines. The first value is the number of lines `n` which I am trying to get using

```
n = awk ‘NR == 1 {print $1}’ test.2
```

but I have no idea how to calculate all the `α` from the test.2 file and then calculate the sum.

The only thing I tested this far is

```
for i in $(seq 1 "${n}"); do
        i=$((i+1))
        a=awk 'NR == $i {print $2}' test.2
        x=$(awk -F'[-,]' '({print sqrt((a[{$i}]-2a[${i}+1]+a[${i}+2])ˆ2)}')
        stdev=$x/(n-2)
done

echo "$stdev"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be roughly like this, but you need to test and correct.

```
awk '                                    
NR == 1 { n = $1 }                       
NR > 1 {                                 
 a[0] = a[1];                            
 a[1] = a[2];                            
 a[2] = $2;                              
 if (NR > 3) {                           
   row_value = ( a[0] - 2 * a[1] + a[2] )
   if (row_value < 0) {                  
     row_value = - row_value             
   }                                     
   sum += row_value                      
 }                                       
}                                        
END { print sum / (n - 2) }' test.2
```

Comment: I do not get the logic of this. It is printing multiple values while it should only print one if I am not mistaken. Because, according to the formula you would do the sum for the first three values, then, from the second one the next three values and so on until you get all the values

Comment: ok updated, but as I said you can fix any issues. I only want to show how you should approach this in awk. I left out the absolute value part too.

Comment: I understand, thank you. For the absolute part shouldn't I just add a `sqrt` and a `ˆ2`  though?

Comment: That's a great idea yes, you could also write an abs function.

Comment: I understand most of the code, only the `a[0]=a[1]` and `a[1]=a[2]` I am not understanding

Comment: as we scan each line, we need to refer to next two lines (`a_{i+1}` and `a_{i+2}`). Since this is not possible, the code instead looks at the previous two lines. When reading the line starting with `3`, `a[0]` will be `4.4278` and `a[1]` will be `6.9588`. To accomplish this we shift the a's as we read new lines.

Comment: I understand, thanks! Only one more question, you say `when reading the line starting with 3` does this mean it will read the first 3 lines and move on to the next three? Because according to the formula it should read the values `4.4278`,  `6.9588` and `6.5200` and then `6.9588`, `6.5200` and `6.4927` and so on..

Comment: No, it should read every line in order right? We are working on a 3 number sliding window. The only issue is, for the first two lines we don't calculate anything because we are waiting for a[2] to be 6.5200.

Comment: I tried calculating the equation with python and I got a very different result

Comment: I think it is because the script does not stop on the number of records - 3, because the last (a{i}) should be the third to last record so the next to could be calculated and not exceed the range of the data.

Comment: I don't think so but it may be because the `n` was wrong. Updated the script can you check this version?